# Unable to publish a SQL Server Database Trial Tier, from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

Trying to publish a new database from Visual Studio 2013 I get the following error message:

> The operation is not supported for your subscription offer type

I am on the trial tier, but I should be able to create a database. Indeed, when attempting to create a database directly in the Azure portal I have no such issues.

Is this a known issue? Any workarounds please?

Comment: Do you have multiple Azure Subscriptions?

Comment: No, just the trial one.